# How can I build three buttons touching horizontally in Unity GUI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, button

[image]

I'm trying to build a custom EditorWindow in Unity  and I want to have the effect like in the picture with the buttons acting like tabs.

I tried to place the buttons horizontally and have negative spaces between them but is not quite the effect I want. Below is my code.

```
        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();

        if (GUILayout.Button("Heightmap")) { }
        GUILayout.Space(-10);
        if (GUILayout.Button("Vegetation")) { }
        GUILayout.Space(-10);
        if (GUILayout.Button("Details")){ }

        GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
```

Comment: Try to scratch from here: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/2019.1/Editor/Mono/SettingsWindow/LightingEditor.cs This is the source code of the editor used for the Lighting window that you are showing. And if you find it, post it please, I've been digging for a while but didn't find it ^^'

Comment: @Lotan See my answer below

Comment: Thanks @Ruzihm, as allways, two steps ahead ^^'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GUILayout.Toolbar`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUILayout.Toolbar.html):

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class MyWindow : EditorWindow
{
    int toolbarInt = 0;
    string[] toolbarStrings = {"Heightmap", "Vegetation", "Details"};

    // Add menu named "My Window" to the Window menu
    [MenuItem("Window/My Window")]
    static void Init()
    {
        // Get existing open window or if none, make a new one:
        MyWindow window = (MyWindow)EditorWindow.GetWindow(typeof(MyWindow));
        window.Show();
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        toolbarInt = GUILayout.Toolbar(toolbarInt, toolbarStrings);

        switch (toolbarInt)
        {
            case 0:
            GUILayout.Button("Content for Heightmap");
            break;

            case 1:
            GUILayout.Button("Content for Vegetation");
            break;

            case 2:
            GUILayout.Button("Button for Details");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```